# Need to break down a python dictionary with array values

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a python dictionary that looks like:

```
dictionary = {
    'a' : ['@'],
    's' : ['$', '5', 'z'],
    'o' : ['0', '()']
}
```

I need it to be broken down into:

```
   [{
     'a' : ['@'],
     's' : ['$'],
     'o' : ['0']
    },
    {
     'a' : ['@'],
     's' : ['5'],
     'o' : ['0']
    },
    {
     'a' : ['@'],
     's' : ['z'],
     'o' : ['0']
    },
    {
     'a' : ['@'],
     's' : ['$'],
     'o' : ['()']
    },
    {
     'a' : ['@'],
     's' : ['5'],
     'o' : ['()']
    },
    {
     'a' : ['@'],
     's' : ['z'],
     'o' : ['()']
    }]
```

All keys in the dictionary have a value that is a list of strings, the solution has to break down items of each list into individual string and generate new dictionaries with one key having one value, while considering all possible combinations.

And the solution must work for similar dictionary of all sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
spam = {
    'a' : ['@'],
    's' : ['$', '5', 'z'],
    'o' : ['0', '()']
}

from itertools import product
eggs = [dict(zip(spam.keys(), ([sub_item] for sub_item in item)))
        for item in product(*spam.values())]
print(eggs)
```

output

```
[{'a': ['@'], 's': ['$'], 'o': ['0']}, {'a': ['@'], 's': ['$'], 'o': ['()']}, {'a': ['@'], 's': ['5'], 'o': ['0']}, {'a': ['@'], 's': ['5'], 'o': ['()']}, {'a': ['@'], 's': ['z'], 'o': ['0']}, {'a': ['@'], 's': ['z'], 'o': ['()']}]
```

Comment: This is not the required output though.

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.product` is the obvious way to get all the combinations, but the challenge here is that it yields the permutations in the wrong order.  If you reverse both the inputs and the outputs to the function, this will give the required order.

You also want the values in the output sub-dictionary to be one-element lists; here this is handled by the `[v]` (in place of just `v`) inside the dictionary comprehension.

```
from pprint import pprint
from itertools import product

dictionary = {
    'a' : ['@'],
    's' : ['$', '5', 'z'],
    'o' : ['0', '()']
}

out =  [
    {k:[v] for k, v in zip(dictionary.keys(), reversed(x))}
    for x in product(*reversed(list(dictionary.values())))
]

pprint(out)
```

Gives:

```
[{'a': ['@'], 'o': ['0'], 's': ['$']},
 {'a': ['@'], 'o': ['0'], 's': ['5']},
 {'a': ['@'], 'o': ['0'], 's': ['z']},
 {'a': ['@'], 'o': ['()'], 's': ['$']},
 {'a': ['@'], 'o': ['()'], 's': ['5']},
 {'a': ['@'], 'o': ['()'], 's': ['z']}]
```

(Note: in fact the elements of each dictionary will be in the correct order for versions of Python that support this, i.e. >= 3.7, although here I am using a version of `pprint` that sorts dictionary keys alphabetically.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion with a generator for a no-import solution:

```
def combos(d, c = []):
  if not d:
    yield dict(c)
  else:
    yield from [i for a, b in d[0] for i in combos(d[1:], c+[(a, [b])])]

d = {'a': ['@'], 's': ['$', '5', 'z'], 'o': ['0', '()']}
print(list(combos([[[a, i] for i in b] for a, b in d.items()])))
```

Output:

```
[{'a': ['@'], 's': ['$'], 'o': ['0']}, {'a': ['@'], 's': ['$'], 'o': ['()']}, {'a': ['@'], 's': ['5'], 'o': ['0']}, {'a': ['@'], 's': ['5'], 'o': ['()']}, {'a': ['@'], 's': ['z'], 'o': ['0']}, {'a': ['@'], 's': ['z'], 'o': ['()']}]
```